# Which overload is called and how?

Tags: c#, .net

I wrote some extensions methods to handle the css class like how you would do it in jQuery. Since I'm using ASP.NET the framework has two extension points i need to handle.

The first one is `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl`

```
public static bool HasCssClass(this WebControl control, string className)
public static void AddCssClass(this WebControl control, string className)
public static void RemoveCssClass(this WebControl control, string className)
```

and the second one is System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor

```
public static bool HasCssClass(this IAttributeAccessor accessor, string className)
public static void AddCssClass(this IAttributeAccessor accessor, string className)
public static void RemoveCssClass(this IAttributeAccessor accessor, string className)
```

the dilemma here has to do with that the CssClass property of WebControl doesn't seem to reflect accordingly when you access the property through the IAttributeAccessor interface.

i.e.

```
WebControl c;
c.CssClass = "hello-world";
Debug.Assert(((IAttributeSelector)c).GetAttribute("class") != "hello-world");
```

I did some digging around with the .NET Reflector and came to the conclusion that the assertion will hold. I can modify the same underlying HTML property `class` in two distinct ways. Thus my problem, which overload do I use, or rather, which overload does the compiler use?

Now, `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl` implements `System.Web.UI.IAttributeAccessor` and this is why I ask the question, which overload will be used? Or is the call ambiguous between the two?

I always imagine that the compiler/run-time calculated the distance to pick one type over the other.

Say `TextBox`, which derives from `WebControl` that implements `IAttributeAccessor` would call the `WebControl` overload because the distance to `WebControl` is shorter, strictly speaking.

I found some stuff on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691338(VS.71).aspx) about this, however, it doesn't say what it means to be better than or worse than. So what's going to happen when I call.

```
TextBox c;
c.AddCssClass("hello-world");
```

?

## EDIT

I ended up changing the IAttributeAccessor to HtmlControl instead, becuase it still covers most cases and would be less confusing for other developers on my team.

IntelliSense actually displayed both as possible overloads, while only one, in fact, is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were nearly there - you wanted section [7.4.2.3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339(VS.71).aspx) instead - "better conversion". It's not a matter of conversion "distance" though. (In the C# 3 spec this is 7.4.3.4 in case you're interested.)

The conversion from `TextBox` to `WebControl` is better than the conversion to `IAttributeSelector`, because:

> If an implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 
>   exists, C1 is the better conversion.

There's an implicit conversion from `WebControl` to `IAttributeSelector` but not vice versa.

Now that we know which conversion is better, we can apply the section you referenced to determine that the overload with `WebControl` will be picked. This can easily be demonstrated with a test application of course:

```
using System;

public interface IFoo {}
public class Bar : IFoo {}
public class Baz : Bar {}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Extension(this IFoo foo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Extension(IFoo)");
    }

    public static void Extension(this Bar bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Extension(Bar)");
    }
}

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Baz b = new Baz();
        b.Extension();
    }
}
```

This prints "Extension(Bar)" - corresponding to the extension method via `WebControl` in your real case.

Of course, if you cast to `b` to `IFoo` then the overload printing "Extension(IFoo)" will be picked - because the compiler doesn't know that the other overload will be applicable. Remember that overloading is *only* performed at compile time (leaving aside `dynamic` in C# 4).

Comment: I think i got it, but I had to write it down several times before it was clear. T1 is WebControl, T2 is IAttributeAccessor, S is TextBox and has an implicit conversion to both but IAttributeAccessor does not have an implicit conversion to WebControl. T1 is the type. Do you know if there is a formal name for this? And as always I'm amazed over how you find the time to answer all these questions ;) Thanks! But if T1 is T2, but T2 isn't T1, doesn't that imply a distance? When the distance is the same, there's a rule for working out an ambiguity but the distance argument seems true to some extent.

Comment: @John: I suspect you can get quite far using a "distance" analogy and intuition, but I prefer to deal with the terms in the spec - they're easier to reason from, and it's a common frame of reference for communication. I'm sure there will be some corner cases which the "distance" analogy doesn't work with. As for a formal name - a name for what, exactly? Overload resolution, determining the "better" function member, determining the "better" conversion?

Comment: Agreed, I was just thinking in terms of type theory, if this is a well know way of dealing with overload resolution. Can I rely on the same principe for say outher staically typed programming languages such as Java.

Comment: @John: Each language is going to have its own set of rules, and they may well be subtly different. It becomes more interesting when you get overloads introduced in derived classes etc... See the first example here, for instance: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html

Comment: That's wicked... S is int, I don't see it. What makes object the better overload, and this clearly dispoves the distance argument. Anyway, when I read this, If S is T1, C1 is the better conversion. I look at it and think, it implies that no conversion takes place and when you reverse it, If S is T2, C2 is the better conversion, then that implies an ambiguity. There's no mention an ambiguity in 7.4.2.3. so that can't be it, then I look in 7.4.2.2 and conclude that for this to compile at least one argument has to have a better conversion. That is, the boxing is somehow a better conversion.

Comment: @John: In that case it's not a matter of conversions - the overload for `int` isn't even considered, because of the way overloads are found. The compiler stops at the most derived class, and the only *new* signature that introduces is the `object` one.

Comment: I read the answer later... but why would the compiler do such a thing in the first place? Why is a method from the most derived class higher up the list? What reasoning is behind making such a choice?

Comment: @John: It's for versioning reasons, basically. It's to avoid the "brittle base class" problem, where introducing a new method in the base class changes the meaning of an existing method call. I think that's reasonable *except* in the case where the derived class is also overriding that method.

Comment: Okay, I see now. I bet I won't run into any troubles caused by this in the near future but it's good to have a handle on things. Thank you.