# Overloads Done At Compile Time

Tags: c#

I was just reading this answer

[Which overload is called and how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037868/which-overload-is-called-and-how/2037885#2037885)

by Jon Skeet and I just done understand how overload resolution gets done at compile time - How is that possible??  You dont know the type of the object till you run??

I always thought that all method calls were done at run time (late binding)

What are the exceptions to that??

I ll give an example:

```
public void DoWork(IFoo)
public void DoWork(Bar) 

IFoo a = new Bar();
DoWork(a)
```

Which method gets called here and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a method call is encountered by the compiler the types of all the parameters are known because C# is a statically-typed language: all expressions and variables are of a particular type and that type is definite and known at compile time.

This is ignoring `dynamic` which slightly complicates things.

Edit: This is a response to your edit. For clarity, I translated your code into the following:

```
interface IFoo { }
class Bar : IFoo { }
class Test {
    public void DoWork(IFoo a) { }
    public void DoWork(Bar b) { }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        IFoo a = new Bar();
        Test t = new Test();
        t.DoWork(a);
    }
}
```

You are asking which method is called here (`Test.DoWork(IFoo)` or `Test.DoWork(Bar)`) when invoked as `t.DoWork(a)` in `Main`. The answer is that `Test.DoWork(IFoo)` is called. This is basically because the the parameter is typed as an `IFoo`. Let's go the specification (§7.4.3.1):

> A function member is said to be an applicable function member with respect to an argument list A when all of the following are true:
>
> The number of arguments in A is identical to the number of parameters in the function member declaration.
>
> For each argument in A, the parameter passing mode of the argument (i.e., value, ref, or out) is identical to the parameter passing mode of the corresponding parameter, and
>
> **for a value parameter or a parameter array, an implicit conversion (§6.1) exists from the argument to the type of the corresponding parameter**, or
>
> for a ref or out parameter, the type of the argument is identical to the type of the corresponding parameter. After all, a ref or out parameter is an alias for the argument passed.

The issue here (see the bolded statement) is that there is no implicit conversion from `IFoo` to `Bar`. Therefore, the method `Test.DoWork(Bar)` is not an applicable function member. Clearly `Test.DoWork(IFoo)` is an applicable function member and, as the only choice, will be chosen by the compiler as the method to invoke.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing overload resolution with [virtual method dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).  Yes, the runtime type of the object will determine which method to run but the method has already been bound by the compiler.  This is a type-safe way of allowing polymorphic behavior without all the flexibility and danger of true late-binding.

The compiler will determine which method overload in to call based on the types of the arguments as written in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Virtual methods (including calls through an interface) are dispatched on the type of the receiver at runtime (late binding).

Nonvirtual methods are resolved at compile time, using the compile-time type of the reference.  This is why shadowing (the `new` modifier) results in different behaviour depending on whether you call the shadowed method through a base class reference or a derived class reference.

In all cases, overload resolution uses the compile-time types of the arguments.  Only the receiver -- that is, the `x` in a call of the form `x.SomeMethod(y, z)` -- is considered for late binding.  Thus, if `y` is typed as object, and the only overloads are `string y` and `int y`, the compiler will error, even if at runtime `y` would actually be a string or int -- because it's only considering the *compile-time* type (the declared type of the variable).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing decided at runtime is "virtual" functions, you call the appropriate function for your object.